# I can't select a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select a div inside an ul and li but I can't.

This is my html:

```
<ul class="grid">

   <div id='categoria' cat='web'></div>

   <li id='1' data-x="2"><img src="../../images/img5.jpg"></li>

   <li id="category">

      <div class='categories' id='about'>

      </div>

      <div class='categories' id='contact'></div>

      <div id='titulo-web'><h3>Diseño Web</h3></div>
      <div class='categories' id='web'>

      </div>

      <div id='tituloilus'><h3>Ilustracion</h3></div>

      <div class='categories' id='ilustracion'>

      </div>

      <div  style='height:1000px;'></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select de div id='tituloilus' but I can't reach it:

```
$('ul.grid li#category #tituloilus').on('click' , function(){
    alert('You have selected it'); 
});
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Using your html and js it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/n0h19tau/

Comment: Why don't you use just `$('#tituloilus')...` ? Ids should be unique :)

Comment: As folks are pointing out, ID is unique (or should be), so targeting it directly is okay.   Traversing to find certain el0is necessary when it doesn't have a unique identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find it. It has got an ID (*supposed to be unique*)

`$('#tituloilus')` will work

UPDATE :

As you are loading html with ajax, Simple event hanlder will not work, You need to use event delegation

```
$('.grid').on('click','#tituloilus',function(){
   alert("Works").
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, but it doesn't work. $('.grid') works, but not anything inside it.

Comment: @user3444371 do you load the html dynamically with javascript ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I am loading de html with AJAX

Answer (score 8):

If it has `id` attr, why did you select from parent just focus from `id` itself.

```
$('#tituloilus').on('click' , function() { 
     alert('You have selected it'); 
});
```

**[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjithitwizard/8fhyux6s/)**